# abp missing libs directory project mvc

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I just download Abp with this configuration

- Multi Page Web Application
  Web application with server rendered HTML; ASP.NET MVC & jQuery.
- Template Version v8.x
- .NET 7

and libs folder is empty

I just want the content of the lib folder

EmptyLib

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run **abp install-libs**  Make sure Node should be installed

[Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M9NQ.png)

Answer (score 3):

Hi can you open your project in terminal and run `abp install-libs`?